# Java JDBC MySQL exception: "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've been working at this for almost a day and a half now and I can't seem to work this error out. I don't know why the ResultSet is being closed. Maybe some of you can help me out.

MySQLDatabase:

```
package net.gielinor.network.sql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public abstract class MySQLDatabase {

    private String host;
    private String database;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Statement statement;

    public MySQLDatabase(String host, String database, String username, String password) {
        this.host = host;
        this.database = database;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public abstract void cycle() throws SQLException;

    public abstract void ping();

    public void connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s/%s", host, database), username, password);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void ping(String table, String variable) {
        try {
            statement.executeQuery(String.format("SELECT * FROM `%s` WHERE `%s` = 'null'", table, variable));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            connect();
        }
    }

    public ResultSet query(String query) throws SQLException {
        if (query.toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) {
            return statement.executeQuery(query);
        } else {
            statement.executeUpdate(query);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

}
```

MySQLHandler

```
package net.gielinor.network.sql;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import net.gielinor.network.sql.impl.MySQLDonation;

public class MySQLHandler extends Thread {

    private static final MySQLHandler mysqlHandler = new MySQLHandler();

    public static MySQLHandler getMySQLHandler() {
        return mysqlHandler;
    }

    private static List<MySQLDatabase> updateList;
    private static String host;
    private static String database;
    private static String username;
    private static String password;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            for (MySQLDatabase database : updateList) {
                try {
                    if (database.getConnection() == null) {
                        database.connect();
                    } else {
                        database.ping();
                    }
                    database.cycle();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void loadProperties() {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        try {
            p.load(new FileInputStream("./sql.ini"));
            host = p.getProperty("host");
            database = p.getProperty("database");
            username = p.getProperty("username");
            password = p.getProperty("password");   
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error loading MySQL properties.");
        }
    }

    public static String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    static {
        loadProperties();
        updateList = new ArrayList<MySQLDatabase>();
        updateList.add(new MySQLDonation(host, database, username, password));
    }

}
```

MySQLDonation

```
package net.gielinor.network.sql.impl;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import net.gielinor.game.model.player.Client;
import net.gielinor.game.model.player.PlayerHandler;
import net.gielinor.game.model.player.PlayerSave;
import net.gielinor.network.sql.MySQLDatabase;

public final class MySQLDonation extends MySQLDatabase {

    public MySQLDonation(String host, String database, String username, String password) {
        super(host, database, username, password);
    }

    @Override
    public void cycle() throws SQLException {
        ResultSet results = query("SELECT * FROM `gieli436_purchases`.`donations`");
        if (results == null) {
            return;
        }
        while (results.next()) {
            String username = results.getString("username").replace("_", " ");
            System.out.println("name=" + username);
            Client client = (Client) PlayerHandler.getPlayer(username.toLowerCase());
            System.out.println(client == null);
            if (client != null && !client.disconnected) {
                int creditamount = results.getInt("creditamount");
                if (creditamount <= 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                handleDonation(client, creditamount);
                query(String.format("DELETE FROM `gieli436_purchases`.`donations` WHERE `donations`.`username`='%s' LIMIT 1", client.playerName.replaceAll(" ", "_")));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void ping() {
        super.ping("donations", "username");
    }

    private void handleDonation(Client client, int creditamount) throws SQLException {
        client.credits = (client.credits + creditamount);
        client.sendMessage("Thank you for your purchase. You have received " + creditamount + " store credits.");
        PlayerSave.save(client);
    }

}
```

The exception occurs here: in the while loop within MySQLDonation and the actual stacktrace is this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:7077)
    at net.gielinor.network.sql.impl.MySQLDonation.cycle(Unknown Source)
    at net.gielinor.network.sql.MySQLHandler.run(Unknown Source)
```

With this information let me say that this *does* work, I get my message and what not in-game but it repeats, like the user is never removed from the query so it gives them infinite rewards. If you need any more information feel free to ask.

Comment: What does your query function do. It may be closing the ResultSet.

Comment: public ResultSet query(String query) throws SQLException {
    if (query.toLowerCase().startsWith("select")) {
        return statement.executeQuery(query);
    } else {
        statement.executeUpdate(query);
    }
    return null;
}

There is "query", if the string equals select we execute the query; otherwise we send for an update to specified query.

Comment: MySQLDonation.ping call super.ping which is abstract! This code doesn't compile...

Comment: @Aubin how would that be my issue? It's totaly unrelated to the exception. The code compiles fine. MySQLDonation extends MySQLDatabase which is the parent of _ping_ therefore I can call _super.ping(...);_

Comment: @user1787084 what do you pass in the host? Are you absolutely sure that you are getting a connection to the database?

Comment: Positive. My username is printed out from the database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you run the `Delete` query, you use the same `Statement` that was used in the `Select` query. When you re-execute on the same `Statement`, the previous `ResultSet` gets closed.

To avoid this, you should create a new `Statement` everytime you execute a query. So remove `statement = connection.createStatement();` from the `connect()` method in `MySQLDatabase` class, and replace all `statement` in that class to `connection.createStatement()`. You may also choose to delete the private variable `statement` altogether.

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close%28%29).

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense. Would it be my "delete" query causing the issue or the initial query to the table?

Comment: its the delete query. If you take it out of the loop, your code would work, but I believe the logic will be all wrong.

Comment: How so? Mind explaining a little more in depth? Okay, @galuano1, I removed the _statement_ instance and the "query" method and gave every query their own statement.

Comment: come to the chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/28633/chat-with-galuano1?tab=general

Answer (score 2):

this error is some time occur when we use same statement object for diff. types

check Statement objectsss;