# ResultSet closed error, when ResultSet or statement has not been closed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using the tomcat jdbc pool library for MySQL. Very rarely, a user will report seeing the following error:

`Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed`

The error points to the `while(rs.next())` code below, but I can't understand how it's being closed in the first place. The only place I close the resultset, the statement, or the connection is in the `finally` block, which leads me to believe that something in jdbc is automatically closing the resultset/statement if there's an error of some kind.

I've seen similar issues across our app - a connection or statement being closed in the middle of the while loop, like during a batch insert or something.

However, I can find no documentation about this. Here's our code, with unrelated portions removed but explained:

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement s = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {

  conn = getConnection();

  if( conn == null || conn.isClosed() ){
    // ... we do stuff here 
  }

  s = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  rs = s.executeQuery();

  while(rs.next()){ // sometimes, we see "resultset closed" errors here, but we never close them

    try {

      // we read the data, construct an object with, i.e. rs.getString(3)
      // some is json we parse, so we catch exceptions

    } catch (Exception e) {
      if( !rs.isClosed() ){
        // print the primary key to help find the invalid record
      }
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  handleDatabaseException( e );
} finally {
  if(rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch (SQLException ignored) {}
  if(s != null) try { s.close(); } catch (SQLException ignored) {}
  if(conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ignored) {}
}
```

Comment: How long does processing take? Is it an extremely long process? Also, I would suggest you use Java 7 [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Refer this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140178/java-jdbc-mysql-exception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed) and consider adding the `unrelated` portions (in your code).

Comment: Are these all local variables?

Comment: Yes they're all local variables. Unfortunately I have to support java 6 so anything 7+ won't work for me yet. This task doesn't take very long. The sql queries usually take (at most) a few seconds (usually under 1 second), and building the result objects is typically 100ms to 1 second depending on how many results.

Comment: there is no call to ResultSet.next() in the code that you linked to. Can you give more details? Can you show the exception stack trace when the error is encountered?

Comment: Sorry I gave the wrong link. This is correct: https://github.com/prism/Prism/blob/master/src/main/java/me/botsko/prism/actionlibs/ActionsQuery.java#L121. The stack trace: https://pste.me/#/BNo9m