# How to configure MySQL on a very slow environment?

Tags: mysql

My application is installed on a client machine which is really really slow.
I'm getting errors like:

- "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed" (which I believe that occured due to timed out connections)
- "Lock wait timeout exceeded;
  try restarting transaction".

I would like to ensure that all of these errors caused to the slow machine by increasing MySQL timeouts.

My question is - which configurations should I change so that MySQL will be more tolerated to the slow environment.

Thanks

Comment: may be you are using a statement object to query more than once and the previous Result set was already closed..http://stackoverflow.com/a/16140314/1793718

Comment: I'm not, this error never occur in other environments.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try setting your `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` parameter in your my.ini file to resolve the second problem, but i dont really know how to fix the first one. [More on innodb_lock_wait_timeout.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout)