# java mysql resultset error in for loop

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In the below code:

```
String GET_DISTINCT_LISTENER_IDS_QUERY = "select distinct(listener_id) from ";
ResultSet rs = null;
ResultSet rs2 = null;
String temp_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp (id INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',"
        + "date_start DATETIME NULL COMMENT ''," + "listener_id VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '',"
        + "gateway_id VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT ''," + "entryway_id VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT '')";

stmt.executeUpdate(temp_table);

for (int i = 0; i < table_names_list.length; i++) {
    GET_DISTINCT_LISTENER_IDS_QUERY += table_names_list[i];
    PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement(GET_DISTINCT_LISTENER_IDS_QUERY);
    rs = ps1.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        String query = "Select * from " + table_names_list[i] + " where listener_id = ? order by date_start LIMIT 1";
        PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ps2.setString(1, rs.getString("listener_id"));
        rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
        String temp_insert = "INSERT INTO " + table_names_list[i]
                + " (id, date_start, listener_id, gateway_id, entryway_id)" + " values(?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(temp_insert);
        while (rs2.next()) {
            ps.setInt(1, rs2.getInt("id"));
            ps.setDate(2, rs2.getDate("date_start"));
            ps.setString(3, rs2.getString("listener_id"));
            ps.setString(4, rs2.getString("gateway_id"));
            ps.setString(5, rs2.getString("entryway_id"));
            System.out.println("Updating statement...");
            ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above piece of code i am getting a list of table names from the user and then i am iterating over them in the for loop. The code is working but it is not inserting the data into the temp table and ending with an error.

Error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.checkClosed(ResultSet.java:666)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:7274)
    at database.database.main(database.java:62)

62: while (rs.next()) { (this line number 62)
```

Please help me out finding why this error is coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResultSet rs` reference depends on the `Statement stmt` reference that generated it. Since you're changing the statement to execute in `stmt`, `rs` will be closed behind the scenes and won't be able to work anymore.

To solve the problem, just use a single `PreparedStatement` for each `rs` and `rs2`.

Comment: No.. i think it is opposite. As you can see i get the list of listener_id in rs for different tables and then use that for rs2 and the result of rs2 goes into ps

Comment: You said use another PreparedStatement for my update by i am not updating anything in the code. i am just selecting data and inserting data. And for insertion i am already using preparedStatement.

Comment: Fixed the contents. You should use proper names for your variables in the code. Still, the solution is the same: use a single `PreparedStatement` object reference for each `ResultSet` you have/need.

Comment: Ohhhh... Ok... Let me Try. Thanks.

Comment: Code is working and not throwing any errors but still it is not inserting data into the table.

Comment: Probably you're opening a transaction and you're not commiting the results.

Comment: I am. if you see the code i have `ps.executeUpdate()` this statement there which suppose to commit the results.

Comment: AFAIK the only statement to commit results is `Connection#commit`. Another thing: if you want/need to execute DDL statements, you should use `Statement#execute` and not `Statement#executeUpdate`.

Comment: I did what you said in the comment. When i tried to add `connection#commit`, i got error **autocommit=true**. Also i changed the `Statement#executeUpdate` to `Statement#execute` and still not working.

Comment: Well, I don't know what may be happening with your code. Make sure you're using the same database and tables for your operations.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the issue. I was inserting into the wrong table.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(query);` the previous `resultset` i.e. `rs` get closed. More detail can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140178/java-jdbc-mysql-exception-operation-not-allowed-after-resultset-closed)

Comment: Then how can i fix that?

Comment: As Luiggi said use preparedStatement